# Linux: How to remove shared library version dependency

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dependency-management, ldd

Say I have a file `libxxxx.so` which depends on a few other shared libraries like:

```
/usr/lib64/libxxxx.so: /usr/lib64/samba/libdcerpc-samba.so: version `SAMBA_4.1.5' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libxxxx.so)
/usr/lib64/libxxxx.so: /usr/lib64/samba/libmsrpc3.so: version `SAMBA_4.1.5' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libxxxx.so)
/usr/lib64/libxxxx.so: /usr/lib64/samba/libndr-samba.so: version `SAMBA_4.1.5' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libxxxx.so)
```

Now, I put the `libxxxx.so` on another box which *does* contain these exact libraries, installed directly by Samba RPMs. But `ldd` still complains they are not available (this is actual error output). How do I fix this?

Comment: you've got the libraries, but not the proper VERSION of the library. e.g. if you've got SAMBA_4.1.4 (one revision older) then you'll get this kind of error.

Comment: Actually, the Samba is 4.1.5. I understand that I could've got this error if I don't have libraries from the same build. I could have solved this easily if I could build static libraries, at least for Samba in this case. (Sigh)...

Comment: For multi-version libraries, the plain "unversioned" .so filename is usually a symlink to a specific version. e.g. `libndr-samba.so -> libndr-samba-4.x.x.so`. Maybe 4.1.5 is installed, but your unversioned .so is pointing to the wrong version.

Comment: You got a point. I checked that part too. These libraries are not symlinks. (e.g. `-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1.5M Apr  4 10:33 /usr/lib64/samba/libdcerpc-samba.so*`). And of course, the target box is a VM, fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've run ldconfig? Removed /etc/ld.so.cache if there?

Also, have a look around /etc/ld.so.conf* if there, see what the files and conf dirs contain.